# Width different with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

http://www.justfilm.co.uk

I have set up this site to look right in Safari, Firefox and EI8 but in Chrome it is too wide (on Mac, I can't test Chrome on PC).

Here is the code for the container

```
.thrColElsHdr #container {
    width: 64em; 
    background: #FFFFFF; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: left; 
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
   font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your width is in 'em' units. It's dependent on current system font width. Lucida on Mac and PC is very different, I believe.